# How can you make permalink work for custom post type and taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, taxonomy

I have spent days now trying to figure this out, StackOverflow is my last resort. All I want is the following:

http://www.mydomain.com/my-post-stype/my-top-level-category/my-sub-level-category/my-page.html

For posts this is insane easy, just adding /%category%/%postname%.html as a permalink does the trick. However for custom post type this seems insane tough.

I have a registered post_type **project**. And a taxonomy **project_category**

Now I like my permalinks to turn out as

```
/project - Overview of projects in all categories.
/project/CATEGORY - Overview of projects within that category.
/project/CATEGORY/SUBCATEGORY - Overview of projects within that subcategory.
/project/CATEGORY/SUBCATEGORY/postname - The actual post.
```

Probably wp_rewrite needs to help me out here tho I have no clue how. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just gotten my head around Doing something similar.  This is adapted from [this tutorial](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks-part-2)

1. For your post type registration make sure that query_var, publicly_queryable, and has_archive are set to true and rewrite is set to false.
2. Next up is the  [code here](http://snipt.net/funkatronic/permalink-code).

Edit: sorry, but code hinting is completely not working for me today.  Code is in above link

Comment: No prob.  If any help is needing understanding anything for future reference, ask away.

Comment: It did, however, not solve the entire question I am going to repost this going into more details.

Comment: What didn't it solve?